# Error while building openCV 3.0.0 on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, opencv, terminal, cmake

I got to the stage where I successfully populated the build file via CMake (configure and generate).

Once i run `make` when in the build directory via terminal, I get a fatal error at 48%, along with some others before.

```
[ 47%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_mjpeg_decoder.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o
/Users/casparwylie/Desktop/Stuff/Programming/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_qtkit.mm:297:14: warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:100 target:nil selector:@selector(doFireTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
             ^                                         ~~~
1 warning generated.
[ 48%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock", referenced from:
      _videotoolbox_common_end_frame in libavcodec.a(videotoolbox.o)
  "_CMSampleBufferCreate", referenced from:
      _videotoolbox_common_end_frame in libavcodec.a(videotoolbox.o)
  "_CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreate", referenced from:
      _av_videotoolbox_default_init2 in libavcodec.a(videotoolbox.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentOrder", referenced from:
```

What does this error mean, and are there any fixes or work arounds?

Comment: Your compiler does not recognize the C++ code. Either your compiler is to old, in the wrong mode (-std=c+11 or similar might be needed) or the code contains a bug. Can you re-run the compiler with "make VERBOSE=1" and post the line of the compiler call for building cap_qtkit.mm.o

Comment: The result: http://pastebin.com/nPvhWWDM

Comment: ..and http://pastebin.com/0yUxUJd8

Comment: What's your C++ compiler? Call `/usr/bin/c++ --version`

Comment: Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: (thank you for this help, have had 2 days of dead ends and console stress)

Comment: Your question contains a compiler error, your first link is a linker error. How are they related? And it now passes the original target without an compiler error... I don't get it.

Comment: The "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" error is the one causing problem - ignore other one i was also very confused!

Comment: (i updated xcode- this is the newest error when trying to build )

Comment: Then please update your question accordingly. I cannot help you with this new problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case, it was caused by missing ffmpeg. You can install ffmpeg by

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Generally, 'Undefined symbols for arcgitecture...' is related to missing libraries.

Comment: I have the same problem on El Capitan, ffmpeg is installed, compiler is Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: May be you're missing another libs. You can check it here for required packages http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Comment: Adding to the answer, i also needed to link `ffmpeg` apart from installing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem compiling kxmovie and turns out I need to add reference to coremedia framework and videotoolbox framework, after that, linking is fine

Answer (score 0):

Link **coremedia** , **videotoolbox** frameworks in build phases

Answer (score 0):

Link CoreMedia, VideoToolBox, Security frameworks in build phases.

Or you can modify and add following code into opencv-x.x.x/modules/highgui/CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_library(CORE_MEDIA CoreMedia)
if (NOT CORE_MEDIA)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CoreMedia not found")
endif()

find_library(VIDEO_TOOL_BOX VideoToolBox)
if (NOT VIDEO_TOOL_BOX)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "VideoToolBox not found")
endif()

find_library(SECURITY Security)
if (NOT SECURITY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Security not found")
endif()

target_link_libraries(${the_module} ${CORE_MEDIA} ${VIDEO_TOOL_BOX} ${SECURITY})
```

The key point is to use find_library & target_link_libraries in CMakeLists.txt file of opencv_highgui module.

Comment: Had to change this `VideoToolbox` instead of `VideoToolBox` -- case-sensitive filesystem.